# What is the plural of the noun "epistle"?

Tags: plural-forms

What is the plural of the noun *epistle*? Is it *epistles*? Or, is it *epistle*?

I've looked up the word [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epistle)  but there is no information about the plural form.

Comment: Did you scroll down to the examples?

Answer (score 2):

The plural is "epistles".

Google's dictionary can provide you with the plural:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Epistles is correct plural form.
[Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epistles#English)